# Run script after dpkg is installed

Tags: debian, dpkg

While building a dpkg for my Python module, 2 questions came up:

1. Where do I specify the destination where the package goes? I would like it to be installed into one directory by default. It is a python package so spreading out module libraries into /bin /lib ... becomes complicated.
2. If that's not possible to adjust, can I call a script after the package is installed in order to adjust paths in a config file in my application to the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't particularly recommend it, you could put all the files in a single directory hierarchy, then add symlinks so that `usr/bin/yourbin` is a symlink to `../share/yourpackage/yourbin` or whatever.

Your `postinst` should not modify any files you have installed, but it is permissible and not altogether uncommon to have it generate a configuration file in `/etc`, perhaps based on a template in `usr/share/yourpackage/config` or some such. Note that you should take care to mark the generated file as a conffile.

I am using relative paths in `usr` rather than absolute paths in `/usr` quite on purpose, because this is how Debian packages are structured and you need to cope correctly with that. In other words, you cannot assume your package will necessarily be extracted into the root directory.

Comment: Thanks tshepang. Deploying the package processed fine, but the package does not show up in /usr/share/ as other previously installed packages do. I guess I missed some configuration setting? Where would I specify that? I can upload the debian configuration files if you like. The second point I raised becomes obsolete if I can specify where the package goes...

Comment: The answer depends entirely on how you built your `debian/rules`. Sounds like you should post a separate question, with a code snippet.